# Problems creating a captcha in Zend Framework 1.11.11

Tags: zend-framework

How can I create a captcha field when I have created the form using conventional html rather than the addElement() methods of ZF? That might sound stupid, but i'm a novice and after 6 hours of straight googling, still no answer.

Comment: More info would be nice.  Are you using ZF MVC?  Are you using Zend Form at all?  Or perhaps you're trying to use just the captcha.  Code samples would be very helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to add a captcha directly to the view using this code:

```
<?php 
$form = new Zend_Form();
$captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('Captcha', array(
            'captcha' => array(
                'captcha' => 'Image',
                'wordLen' => 6,
                'timeout' => 300,
                'width' => 300,
                'height' => 100,
                'imgUrl' => '/captcha',
                'imgDir' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/captcha',
                'font' => APPLICATION_PATH .     '/../public/fonts/LiberationSansRegular.ttf')));
$form->addElement($captcha);
echo $form;//use this line in view script
$this->view->form = $form //use this line in controller
?>
```

you could also put the same code into your controller, assign it to the view and then call it in the view like:

```
<form>
//form stuff html
<?php echo $this->form->captcha ?>
</form>
```